# await all JDA RestActions

Tags: java, testing, junit, discord, discord-jda

I want to create a (feature) testing system for JDA Discord Bots.

For this, I need to wait until all messages in the current queue are sent(messages are sent with `RestAction#queue`) and test if there is the message.

Is there a way to await all queued `RestAction`s or should I wait exponentially (e.g. wait 0.5 seconds, wait 1 second, wait 2 seconds and test if the message exists)

[Note]
I don't want to change the `queue` to `submit` in my production code and send it to the test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally a testing system shouldn't interact with the internet at all. However, to answer your question you can wait for rest actions by using the promise returned by [submit](https://ci.dv8tion.net/job/JDA/javadoc/net/dv8tion/jda/api/requests/RestAction.html#submit()) instead of using queue.

```java
List<CompletableFuture<?>> list = new ArrayList<>();

list.add(action1.submit());
list.add(action2.submit());
...

CompletableFuture<Void> merged = CompletableFuture.allOf(list.toArray(new CompletableFuture[0]));

merged.whenComplete((v, error) -> {
    if (error != null) error.printStackTrace();
    else System.out.println("All futures completed successfully");
});
```

Comment: The problem is that I don't have access to the method that queues the Button/the submitted Future.