# How to tell if a reaction is removed by a discord bot using JDA?

Tags: java, discord, discord-jda

I have a MessageReactionRemoveEvent in my code and it triggered whenever a reaction is removed.

However, I also have my bot executing some automatic reaction removal (removing the user's reaction).

I want to prevent `MessageReactionRemoveEvent` triggered when the reaction is removed by a bot.

My code for preventing `MessageReactionRemoveEvent` triggered by a bot:

```java
if (event.getMember().getUser().equals(event.getJDA().getSelfUser())) return;
```

But the getUser() method in `MessageReactionRemoveEvent` always returns the ID of the user who reacts instead of the ID of the bot.

My question is how do I detect if a reaction is removed by a bot?

Comment: Why can't you just use User#isBot?

Comment: It is because the MessageReactionRemoveEvent always returns the user who reacts instead of who removes the reaction. Using isBot() will always get false.

Comment: I think that discord does not send that to bots. You may need to cache the reactions by yourself.

Comment: Any source I can reference from? Thank you for your help.

Comment: My fault. I confused something with the caching. You could try to use the audit log.

Comment: Any tutorials I can reference from? I have no idea how the audit log works.

Comment: Hi @dan1st did you solve this problem? I want to give it a try. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58335547/await-all-jda-restactions

Comment: I just worked around this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the `MessageReactionRemoveEvent` will not return the bot ID and therefore I am not able to validate if the reaction is removed by the Bot. I work the other way round to achieve *preventing MessageReactionRemoveEvent triggered when the reaction is removed by a bot*.

Here's how:

1. Add a boolean and let's call it trigger `boolean trigger = true;`.
2. Make sure use `.complete()` to remove reactions instead of `.queue()`, the differences can be seen here: https://ci.dv8tion.net/job/JDA/javadoc/net/dv8tion/jda/api/requests/RestAction.html#queue()
3. After removing a reaction, do `trigger = false;`.
4. Since the .complete() method will *block the current Thread*, `MessageReactionRemoveEvent` will not be called before the code in `MessageReactionAddEvent` is finished.
5. In `MessageReactionRemoveEvent`, simply applies `if (!trigger) // do something`, it means that if the reaction is removed by the bot, code after the if statement won't be executed, and that is where you want to do something if the reaction is removed by a user.
6. At the end of the method, make sure includes `trigger = true;` to reset the trigger.
7. (Optional) Includes `trigger = true;` at the beginning of `MessageReactionAddEvent`.

This works for me like magic.

Comment: I need something like this in Python. Anyone knows how to achieve this with Pythong?
Here's my issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67453836/get-the-user-who-triggered-the-on-raw-reaction-removepayload