# Get the user who triggered the on_raw_reaction_remove(payload)

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am using `async def on_raw_reaction_remove(payload)` to track when a user removes a reaction..
How do I get the user who triggered the event? In my code i have my bot trigger this event by removing reactions in certain scenarios - but when this happens `user = await client.fetch_user(user_id)` always equals to the user who had reacted with the removed reaction and not the bot that removed it  (i need to get the bot as user when the bot removes someone's reaction, so i can say if user == bot: return
I also tried

```
message = await channel.fetch_message(payload.message_id)
guild = message.guild
member = await guild.fetch_member(payload.user_id)
```

but it's the same.. the member is always pointing to the owner of the reaction that was removed, not the bot that's removing the reaction...
How can i get the one who is removing the reaction when using on_raw_reaction_remove?

(if it's relevant - i enabled intents in discord's developer portal and updated my code with

```
intents = discord.Intents.all()
client = discord.Client(intents=intents)
```

Thanks for your help, i wasted so much time on this already :frowning: (new to the discord api)

Comment: That is actually not provided by discords API, so there is no way to do this.

Comment: @Chuaat there is no direct way, but there is a way as in my answer

Answer (score 0):

The answer is - there is nothing in the discord python API that can tell you who removed the reaction.

For my case, I solved it with a workaround - I just had to track if my bot removed a reaction with a variable - I am using a global variable to track when my bot removes a reaction and then just check later if the variable is `True` or `False` and respond accordingly and reset the variable back.

Thanks

Answer (score -3):

What I did in this case was this:

```py
guild = discord.utils.find(lambda g: g.id == payload.guild_id, bot.guilds)
member = discord.utils.find(lambda m: m.id == payload.user_id, guild.members)
```

You now just have to build this into your code

Comment: As the OP says in his question, this returns the id of who added the reaction that got removed.

Comment: This should return a member and not an ID, if this returns an ID I would recommend reinstalling or anything like this as it is impossible that this returns an ID instead of a member

Comment: Unfortunately, I tried that as well.. the member is the same as the user. (the owner of the reaction who got removed) :(

Comment: Just an advice @masky007; If you did all right this works 100%, if you got the payload of the user who added it then you did something wrong. Or if you try getting the guild per the message (what you mentioned in your question) the result you got will happen. Maybe it would be good if you could edit your question with the most important code of your `on_raw_reaction_remove` function

Comment: Hmm @FlexGames i'll test it again and will report back later. Thanks